# Doctrine - one table with tags for multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create Tag entity class, with taxonomy vocabulary, that will be used by multiple entities.
Is there any possibility, to create manytomany relations with three columns?
I need to store tag id, entity id, and entity class name.

So i have now:

```
<?php
/**
 * Taxonomy
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *    name="tag_taxonomy",
 *    indexes={
 *        @ORM\Index(name="tag_taxonomy_namex", columns={"name"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Taxonomy
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="taxonomy", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    protected $tags;
    // .....
}
```

Tag table:

```
<?php
/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="tag",
 *    indexes={
 *        @ORM\Index(name="namex", columns={"name"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Taxonomy", inversedBy="tags", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="taxonomy_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $taxonomy;
    // ....
}
```

Relation table:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="tag_tagging",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="tagging_idx", columns={"tag_id", "entity_name", "record_id"})
 *    },
 *    indexes={
 *        @ORM\Index(name="entity_name_idx", columns={"entity_name", "record_id"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tagging
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="tagging", cascade="ALL")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    protected $tag;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="entity_name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $entityName;
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="record_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $recordId;
    // .....
}
```

So i have already relation table with 3 columns as key:
"tag_id", "entity_name", "record_id".
Now any idea how to create relation with any entity, to tag table?
Maybe Tagging entity is not needed at all?

I wonder what is the best way, to create Tag entity for any entity type.
So i can use tags for Users, Articles, anything.
Of course there can be manytomany relation that will create separate relation table for every entity right? But is the right way?

Comment: Do you need the `Tag` to be inverse side of all those relations at once somehow? Just asking since you put `inversedBy="tagging"` in your `Tagging` entity.

Comment: Suggest you look at [this](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields). It's a very good demonstration of why there are not ManyToMany relations with extra fields in Doctrine. Following their approach will make your coding life much easier.

Comment: @AlanT. I dont.

Comment: @geoB Maybe it is a good example. Two manytoone instead of one manytomany could be the right way ;) I will check it

Comment: Maybe not right on the topic, but these days I use simple array of text or jsonb fields for such things. I'm talking about PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is quite all right even though it won't allow to create a real association (with an underlying foreign key) between any entity and the `Tagging` class. Still, it's perfectly acceptable. What you would need from there is a way to define what would go into your `entityName` field so that it can effectively act as a discriminator field.

As you said, you could also have a separate join table for each entity that can be tagged. That's the solution I am currently using in one of my projects and it is also working fine. In the end, it depends on what operation you want to be able to perform easily.

### Single `Tagging` table/entity

This approach that you selected is also the one presented in the [FPNTagBundle](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle) which integrates its own [DoctrineExtensions-Taggable](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable) library. It relies on a `Tagging` entity that is the owning side of a `ManyToOne` association with your `Tag` table and that holds two fields (`resourceId` and `resourceType`) to refer to the tagged entity.

If you want to go down that path, I recommend that you have a look at the Taggable doctrine extension implementation of the FPNTagBundle. Alternatively, you could look at [this other taggable extension](https://github.com/hilobok/doctrine-extensions-taggable). It's pretty similar but it uses doctrine events in a different way to handle saving/loading.

**Pros:**

- `Tag` can be on the inverse side of its relation with `Tagging`
- Easy to retrieve the IDs of tagged entities for a given tag independently of their type
- Easy to get counts of tagged entities for a given tag even if their type differ (you can even get a count by type with a simple group by)

See the repository proposed by both extensions: [here](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Taggable/Entity/TagRepository.php) and [here](https://github.com/hilobok/doctrine-extensions-taggable/blob/master/lib/Anh/Taggable/Entity/TaggingRepository.php).

**Cons:**

- No "real" association between your entities and `Tag` or `Tagging`
- No foreign key for the relation between `Tagging` and your entities, thus your application has to handle the removal of orphan `Tagging` entries (no way to rely on a `ON DELETE CASCADE`)
- Retrieving the tags of an entity either requires an [extra query](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Taggable/TagManager.php#L212) or a custom join whose result must be handled manually to properly hydrate your `tags` field if you want one in your entity.

### A `ManyToMany` association owned by each taggable entity

With this approach, you end up with a join table for each entity that declares a `ManyToMany` association with your `Tag` entity. To quickly add tags to an entity, I personally use a  `TaggableTrait` like this one:

```
trait TaggableTrait
{    
    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag\Tag") */
    private $tags;

    /* ... getter and add/remove methods ... */
}
```

This way, with a simple `use TaggableTrait` statement in my entities, I can enable tagging.

**Pros:**

- Easy to setup
- You can retrieve the tags of an entity directly with a simple join
- You can filter entities by tags directly with [additional conditions specified by `WITH`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)
- You can rely on your database to remove orphan tagging associations thanks to the foreign keys of your join tables

**Cons:**

- If you want `Tag` to be on the inverse side, you will need to add the inverse of the `ManyToMany` association for each Taggable entity
- You can't simply retrieve all tagged entities for a given tag. You can only do it in a simple way for a given type
- In general, performing operations that act on all taggable entity will be cumbersome *(e.g. I implemented the merging of tags in my project, thus I needed to update all join tables. To do so , I had to work directly with classmetadata and execute native queries to perform my updates on every join table)*

---

Anyway, as I said in the beginning, it all comes down to what kind of operation you want to perform with your tags. Having a generic relation with two fields `resourceId` and `resourceType` inside of a `Tagging` entity might give you a bit more of flexibility inside your application but it will also be a bit trickier to work with when it comes to working with doctrine for some things.

Comment: Thank you for very nice explanation. I can add two things.
1. Single Tagging table/entity - it is a good way if we want to provide dynamic tags adding via admin panel. So users can select taggable entities. With ManyToMany association its impossible.
2. ManyToMany we can use trait sure, but it also can be done by extending class with @MappedSuperclass annotation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html